# Download data from mysql as text file

Tags: php, mysql

I want to add a function that allows users to download their data to a text file. The text file should look a bit like this:

```
Welcome > username
=========================
money : 6286827$
your name : (name from website)
Etc ...
```

Comment: do you mean fetch the data from DB and output `.txt` file to be downloaded by the user, or just save that file locally on server?

Comment: Write a PHP page that formats the data as you want. The user can use the browser's "Save As" menu to save it into a file.

Comment: Maverick maybe understood me :). Yes bro I want file to be downloadd by the user

Comment: This website is the best for me that's why I came here so I hope someone could give me an example

Comment: Mellouki I assume you know how to get data out of your database. So yes then you can use the answer I gave you.

Answer (score 1):

This will automatically download the .txt. Probably the best way to generate .txt files.

**GenerateTxt.php**

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=UserData.txt');
header('Content-type: text/plain');

/* your database stuff  */
/* example in $data array */
$data['username'] = 'Stefan';
$data['money'] = '100000';
$data['name'] = 'My Company';

/* Generate content of text file. */
echo "Welcome > " . $data['username'] . "\r\n";
echo "===================\r\n";
echo "Money : " . $data['money'] . "$\r\n";
echo "Your name : " . $data['name'] . "$\r\n";
```

*Note: newlines (\r\n) in plain-text only works when you use double quotes in your echo.*